# What is time complexity when power involed?

Tags: python-3.x, time-complexity

```
 def f1(lst):
     i=3
     while i<len(lst):
        print(lst[i])
        i **= 3
```

What is the time complexity of this code? the answer says O(loglogn), why?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math.

Comment: On iteration `k`, `i` is `3**3**k`.

Comment: @Wooble: different programming languages have different costs for some operations e.g., `strlen(s)` is `O(n)` in C but `len(s)` is `O(1)` in Python (for builtin sequence types).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: do different programming languages also change what happens to a number when you raise it to the third power, and the relationship of that to the logarithm? Remind me not to use any of those programming languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at how `i` grows with loop (`^` means power here) :

```
i_0 = 3
i_1 = i_0^3 = 3^3
i_2 = i_1^3 = (3^3)^3 = 3^(3*3)
i_3 = i_2^3 = (3^(3*3))^3 = 3^(3*3*3)
...
i_n = 3^(3^n)
```

This is called iterated powers but it is **not** [Tetration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration). As you can see, it is a nested exponentation so the time complexity would be the inverse function : `O(log3(log3(n)))`.